# Can I import Shapefiles into Microsoft SQL Server from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: sql-server, arcgis

I have a business user who has created shapefiles using ArcGIS Pro. We need to be able to share across a wide variety of users who are using Microsoft SQL Server for other geographies. If I have admin access to SQL Server, is there a way in ArcGIS Pro to “save” or import a layer into SQL Server?

Comment: It's been a few years since I worked wtih Esri, but an ArcGis layer has more than just coordinates as you know. So, is the question on how to just share the geo information, or ALL the information contained within a .shp? If it's the latter, or anything between that and the former, SQL Server isn't what you want. I'd just use a fileshare, FTP site, Dropbox, etc... I can see the import and export getting real ugly. There is the [enterprise geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-sql-server/setup-geodatabase-sqlserver.htm) though.

Comment: This sounds like a question suitable for the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.